# Setting a file drop zone behind a table full with data

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm using the ngx-file-drop module for angular 4.

In the last few days I tried to add a file-drop possibility to a website.
The site shows data in a table. Many things are loaded with *ngFor and *ngIf.
I wanted the drop zone to be in the background (behind the table but same size as table). The drop-zone should only appear if something was dragged into the zone. The drop-zone should only be a dotted border around the drop-zone.
My problem was, that the dragover event fired hundreds of change events on the site and the data in the table and the header we're loaded again and again... So the website was very, very slow...

**Second try:**
So I decided to make the table invisible (again a *ngIf) if something is dragged into the zone --> less things to load.
Worked until I noticed, that I've set the "drop-zone-div" as absolute.
So the data in the table (also buttons) weren't accessible, respectively not clickable.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve my problem for the first try or second try?

[image: Jira drag and drop]
It should basically work like the jira drag and drop..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
Now, I hide the table and the header while dragging files over the page.
I added a placeholder in the table, which is only visible, if I'm actually dragging, so the page remains large enough.

With some javascript I'm calculating the needed size for the placeholder.

`const myElement = document.getElementByClassName('class-name')[0];`

`const height = myElement.clientHeight;`